# Can't Install build-essential on CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation

When I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I get the following error message:

```
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package build-essential
```

Comment: What distro (Ubuntu? Debian?) and version?  What repo?

Comment: Linux version 2.6.18-028stab070.14 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010
Is that correct ?

Comment: CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

Comment: Are you running a Red Hat kernel on a Debian or Ubuntu distribution? Or are you actually running a Red Hat distribution? If you're running a Red Hat distribution, then you should be using `yum` or `up2date` (whichever is appropriate for your distribution version).

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys! Googling how to install build-essential for CentOS pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Here's the cmd: sudo yum install -y libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel

Comment: don't forget to add that as an _answer_ and _accept_ it once the stack software lets you do that. :)

Comment: @Waley The command you post is to install xml and xslt development libraries. As a side effect it will install gcc. Something more in the spirit of debian's build-essential will be `sudo yum install gcc gcc-cpp make rpm-build`

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I believe this still should work.

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

Comment: this will install every single development tools available, just FYI

Comment: See `yum group info "Development Tools"` for list of packages installed

Comment: It's a long way short of all development tools, in case you're worried. It's mostly the basics for c/c++ with automake, autoconf etc.

Comment: But if you only need a configure/make/make install to work it may still be too much (e.g. it includes git and subversion). It's better to start with Ketan Patel's yum install and if something is still missing go for this one

Comment: it depends on the "programming language" needed, but if you expect to compile c++, you'll need in PLUS `glibc-devel` and maybe `make`... yum groups are soooo shitty !

Answer (score 72):

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ make
```

This works equivalent of `build-essential` in CentOS.

Comment: `openssl-devel` might coincidentally pull in the stuff you want, but isn't properly `build-essential` itself.

Comment: @tripleee Indeed. Good catch, make and cmake will definitely will need this. By the way I would like to add that some times I also need to install separately : glibc-devel.i686 libstdc++-devel.i686 openssl-devel.i686 , in order to have a 64bit build.

Answer (score 8):

The metapackage [`build-essential`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/build-essential) is provided on Debian to collect all the commonly required essential build tools in the Debian build chain, including those you need to create `.deb` packages. Centos uses a different package manager altogether and does not directly provide anything like this; you'll need to manually install the individual components of the toolchain (`gcc`, `make`, common development libraries, documentation, etc, as well as of course the tools to create RPM packages if you want to do that).

If you drop the `.deb` or RPM stuff, `gcc`, `gcc-c++`, `glibc-devel`, and `make` should get the corresponding Centos packages currently.

Comment: As per [@PabloCastellazzi's old comment](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16422/cant-install-build-essential-on-centos#comment22182_16422)  you can  get an RPM tool chain with the package `rpm-build`. The actual utility's name is `rpmbuild`. For more information, see e.g. https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment

Answer (score 3):

I combined accepted solution from Scott Likens with the comment from user12345, and first looked at what was in the "Development Tools" group before installing.

As user12345 pointed out, you can do this with:

```
$ yum group info "Development Tools"
```

I did want to install packages like `autoconf` and `automake` and `binutils`, but I did not need `doxygen` or `ant` or `mercurial`.

Below is the list I used, along with their dependencies, but of course, your mileage may vary, depending upon YOUR needs.

```
$ yum install \
    autoconf automake binutils \
    bison flex gcc gcc-c++ gettext \
    libtool make patch pkgconfig \
    redhat-rpm-config rpm-build rpm-sign \
    ctags elfutils indent patchutils
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo yum install -y libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

Comment: This seems more of a side-effect as @pablo-castellazzi mentioned in comments in your question section. Better answer imo is by [K.K. Patel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63068/17395) or [Scott Likens](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32439/17395)

Comment: The command you post asks to install xml and xslt development libraries. As a side effect it will install gcc which is an essential building tool.